# Terraform plan err: Unsupported argument

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a resource like this `repo/dynamo/main.tf`:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "infra_locks" {
  name         = "infra-locks"
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "LockID"
  attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }
}
```

And I refer above file as a module follow [github repo](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-dynamodb-table)

Tf file where I refer to above file `repo/example/main.tf`:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
}

module "dynamodb_table" {
  source = "../dynamodb_table"

  name      = "my-table"
}
```

I have `terraform init` success but fail when run `terraform plan`

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 14, in module "dynamodb_table":
  14:   name      = "my-table"

An argument named "name" is not expected here.
```

How can i fix this?
Tks in advance

Comment: Well, is the module from github or is it from `"../dynamodb_table"`? Currently you reference a local module, does that module have a `name` variable?

Comment: Yes, I use it from local, I have init success ```Initializing modules...
- dynamo_table in ../dynamo

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Reusing previous version of hashicorp/aws from the dependency lock file
- Using previously-installed hashicorp/aws v3.34.0

Terraform has been successfully initialized!```

Comment: Then the github link is irrelevant and the question is: does your local `dynamodb_table` have a `name` variable? The answer probably is: no.

Comment: @luk2302 I have show the dynamo/main.tf in beginning of the question, it has name attribute

Comment: That is not a variable.

Comment: Tks, I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @luk2302 has said:

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "infra_locks" {}
```

The above resource exactly has `name` attribute but it 's not a variable so we can not assign anything to it.

There is a confused right here.
I have fixed by change a little bit: `repo/dynamo/main.tf`

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "infra_locks" {
  name         = var.name
  billing_mode = "PAY_PER_REQUEST"
  hash_key     = "LockID"
  attribute {
    name = "LockID"
    type = "S"
  }
}
```

`repo/dynamo/variable.tf`

```
variable "name" {
  description = "dynamo table name"
  default     = null
}
```

And final, we can configure your `dynamo_table` 's name.